# How to increase the width of a LATEX column

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table whose latex code is:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{ABCD} & first col & second col & \multicolumn{2}{c}{third col} \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{DF}                                 \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & 1         & 2          & 3             & 4             \\ \cline{1-1}
AB                    & 98        & 65         & 33            & 64            \\
CD                    & 45        & 44         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-}         \\
EF                    & 56        & 67         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-}         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and finaly the latex table is here:

[image]

The spacing between 3 & 4 is not same as 1 & 2. This is because 1, 2 are in first and second column, respectively and 3 and 4 are in third column. How can I increase the width of third column so that the column widths 1-2-3-4 are uniform.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... use `tabularx` for better usage...

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{c*{4}{wc{4em}}}` (needs the `array` package)  should get you started.

Comment: I had similar issue and this link was helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29259/how-to-globally-adjust-horizontal-spacing-in-table-length

Comment: @Kidegalize although that is an old question so none of the answers mention the`w` column width specifier that leandriis just mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the help. Would that be possible to modify the latex code i have attached. I am new to latex table and not able to follow the answer. Thank you very much for your help. I used latex table generator to create the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx, multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}

    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{ABCD} 
        & first col 
            & second col 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{third col} \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{DF}                \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
        & 1         
            & 2          
                & 3             
                    & 4                         \\ 
    AB                    
        & 98        
            & 65         
                & 33            
                    & 64                        \\
    CD                    
        & 45        
            & 44         
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-}         \\
    EF                    
        & 56        
            & 67         
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-}         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx, multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec = cccccc,
        cell{1}{1} = {r=3}{c}, % multirow
        cell{1}{4} = {c=3}{c}, % multicolumn
        cell{2}{2} = {c=5}{c}, % multicolumn
        cell{5,6}{5} = {c=1}{c}, % multicolumn
        hspan = even, % distribute extra space evenly
        colsep = 4pt,
    }

    \hline
    ABCD
        & {first \\col} 
            & {second\\ col} 
                & {third \\col} \\ \cline{2-6} 
        & DF                \\ \cline{2-6} 
        & 1         
            & 2          
                & 3  &           
                    & 4                         \\ 
    AB                    
        & 98        
            & 65         
                & 33 &           
                    & 64                        \\
    CD                    
        & 45        
            & 44  &       
                & -         \\
    EF                    
        & 56        
            & 67   &      
                & -         \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. The code works perfect. Is it possible to increase the width of only the third column.  I think the code in its current form increases the width of all columns in same amount. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lalu please see the edit to the answer